# Back button on actionBar does not work

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, icons

I have a `<` button on actionBar beside the app title and a `+` button.

[image]

I create the `<` button by using code below

```
 final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.back_to);
```

and then

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  // for + button
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.create_new_details, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home: // back to previous activity, < button
                onBackPressed();
            break;

            case R.id.addDetails:
                mClickedPosition = -1;
                View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.addDetails);
                PopupMenu po = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); //for drop-down menu
                po.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_details, po.getMenu());
                po.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if ("Add Work Details".equals(item.getTitle())) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Add_Details_Information.class);  // go to Details class
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                        } else {

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                po.show(); //showing popup menu
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

But only the + button works. How do I back to previous activity when < button is clicked?

Comment: `R.id.home` needs to be `android.R.id.home`.

Comment: see here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: @MikeM. why I can use  `case R.id.home:` if only has one button on ActionBar ?

Comment: So is the issue resolved?

Comment: @4k3R ya, after added `android` in front

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The Home Button has a specific ID, which is in the system Resources. You have to use that ID for your method to work.

Comment: @MikeM. If the action bar only has one button, I can use `case R.id.home:`. But if I have two button, I need to use `android.case R.id.home`. Why?

Comment: When you create that Button on the right side, you're defining its ID, so it's going to be in your package's Resources; just plain `R`. The Home Button is created by the system, so its ID is in the system Resources; `android.R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `R.id.home` to `android.R.id.home`.